# Android accessibility identify heading

Tags: android, heading, accessibility

I have the latest version of Talkback and its announcing "My Top level Text Heading". Android native behaviour is adding "Heading" for my top level elements. I could not find a way to switch ON/OFF heading announcement. Is there an API to control its behaviour. In the previous version of Talkback versions it was not announcing "Heading" by itself.

Comment: What kind of control are you using to get it to read this? I have the opposite problem, I WANT it to read heading and have been having to put it in manually on the content description.

Comment: @Mr_E Were you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 9):

You can enable or disable the "heading" accessibility property of any `View` on API 19+:

```java
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(headingView, new AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
  @Override
  public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
    info.setHeading(true); // false to mark a view as not a heading
  }
});
```

If you have minSdk 28, you can simply set this directly in your XML:

```xml
android:accessibilityHeading="false"
```

Comment: in which API this method added? `AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat#setHeading(boolean)`

Comment: Hi @Adam S , this does not appear to work for me. The textview is not announcing that it is a heading when you do `setHeading(true)`.

Comment: Yup, it's added in 28 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo#setHeading(boolean)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simpler method:

```java
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityHeading(headingView, false);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ViewCompat#setAccessibilityHeading(android.view.View,%20boolean)

Comment: It's for 19 and lower.

Comment: @KornilovRuslan The doc says that this is a no-op on API < 19

Answer (score 1):

If you're only supporting API level 23 and above, you can simply do the following.

```
textView.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
  @Override
  public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
    //blanked to prevent talkback from announcing class/type
    info.setClassName("");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by passing heading as false in

```
AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.CollectionItemInfoCompat.obtain method.

        // set the heading attribute to false so that heading is not announced in label  

info.setCollectionItemInfo(
    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.CollectionItemInfoCompat.obtain(glp.getSpanIndex(),
 glp.getSpanSize(), spanGroupIndex, 1, false, false));

public static CollectionItemInfoCompat obtain(int rowIndex, 
int rowSpan, int columnIndex, int columnSpan,
boolean heading, boolean selected)
```

Comment: how do you get glp, Or what's glp?